# Compiler Error With "DoesNotReturn" Attribute

Tags: c#, code-analysis, c#-8.0

I have implemented some static throw helper methods in a net-standard 2.1 (C# 8.0) project.

```cs
[DoesNotReturn]
public static void InvalidOperation(String message, String caller, String path, Int32 line)
{
  throw new InvalidOperationException($"{message}\n{caller}|{path}|{line}");
}
```

I want to use them in a NET 5.0 project like:

```cs
public static BitmapSource GetBitmapSource(String uri)
{
    if (Uri.TryCreate(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out Uri? _uri))
    {
        return new BitmapImage(_uri);
    }

    Throw.InvalidOperation( $"Invalid uri {uri}.");
}
```

But the the compiler still returns the error CS0161: "Not all code paths return a value"

Comment: `puplic`? Ok, you should not use throwing exceptions with methods like `Throw.InvalidOperation( $"Invalid uri {uri}.");` You may do exception fablic and use like: `throw MyExceptionGenerator.InvalidOperation($"Invalid uri {uri}.");`, but best practice is generate Exceptions by `new` operator - you should generate the new exception class and use like: `throw new MyInvalidOperaionException($"Invalid uri {uri}.")`

Comment: I like to use the CallerMemberName, CallerFilePath, and CallerLineAttributes to locate where the exception was thrown. That's why I am using those helper methods. I have seen those helper methods several times. Like here: https://endjin.com/blog/2020/08/dotnet-csharp-8-nullable-references-when-methods-dont-return

Comment: The attributes can help the compiler in terms of additional analysis, but as far as I'm aware they still don't allow you to violate the language rules of reachability... the end of your method is still reachable as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: That was not what I wanted to hear, Mr. Skeet. :-( But nevertheless, thanks for clarification.

Comment: Thats similar to ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw. We knows the lines after it are unreachable but the language requires a return. You can put a dummy return or throw null but it's not the nicest thing... Or just switch to the suggestion in the comment above, `throw ThrowHelper.Whatever()` or switch the order you perform your checks

Comment: I *think* that DoesNotReturn helps more with nullability analysis than anything else. Ie. it helps the compiler understand that the nullable state of variables passed into a method won't be altered afterwards *if/when* the method doesn't return

Comment: I find the notion that one "should not" write methods that always throw sort of unsatisfying. What about `Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR`? What was `DoesNotReturn` created for _except_ that there are cases where the compiler needs to know that a particular function never returns to avoid spurious errors? Surely the issue here is simply that no one has yet bothered to track down all the cases where it might be useful.

FWIW I kind of like TypeScript's `never` type for handling cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the exceptional path first:

```
public static BitmapSource GetBitmapSource(String uri)
{
    if (!Uri.TryCreate(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out Uri? _uri))
    {
        Throw.InvalidOperation( $"Invalid uri {uri}.");
    }

    return new BitmapImage(_uri);
}
```

Now, as far as the compiler is concerned, the method returns.

---

Another thing to consider is to have the helper method return the exception, instead of throwing it. The method that calls it can throw it. That way the compiler would know that it throws. Which also means you don't get the helper method in the stack trace of the exception.

---

*By the way, for reference of people finding this, I believe the helper method in the question is intended to use these: [Reserved attributes: Determine caller information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information).*

Comment: Thanks. Returning an exception instead of throwing seems to be the best solution in most cases. I simply expected the compiler would infer reachability from the attribute. And yes, I did mean the linked caller attributes. Thanks for clarification.